# Installing libgd2 in Suse

Tags: opensuse

I normally work on CentOS and Ubuntu machines but I have been busting my head against the wall trying to install libgd2 on Suse (Suse Enterprise Server 11. x86_64). Plenty of google searches point me to install gd but that's version 1. Even a zypper search "gd" only yields "gd - A drawing library for programs that use PNG and JPEG Output".
Ultimately I am trying to install Perl's GD module but it depends on libgd2 and trying to install from source is also throwing error after error. 
Mostly ...

```
configure.ac:51: warning: macro `AM_ICONV' not found in library
configure.ac:51: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_ICONV        
If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
See the Autoconf documentation.
Failed
```

On CentOS and Ubuntu installing libgd2 is a one liner and that's that but unfortunately I'm stuck with trying to get it to work on Suse.

Has anyone ever installed libgd2 on a Suse box before? Or if you know the magic command for zypper that would be great too.

Many thanks!
Janie

Answer (score 1):

Install development libraries for gettext (gettext-devel under opensuse, I presume), clean everything and configure again.